# Fullpage.js + figcaption + lazyload fade in

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js, lazy-loading

I am a beginner and a none professional programmer trying to make a web page for my little architecture company.  I came across Fullpage.js and I thought I should give it a try. See http://codepen.io/nor159/pen/RayPZB.

```
<section class="section">
<figure class="slide">
  <img data-src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/600">
  <figcaption>Section 1, slide 1/4</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="slide">
  <img data-src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/300">
  <figcaption>Section 1, slide 2/4</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="slide">
  <img data-src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
  <figcaption>Section 1, slide 3/4</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="slide">
  <img data-src="http://placekitten.com/g/1200/400">
  <figcaption>Section 1, slide 4/4</figcaption>
</figure>
</section>
```

Now I have 2 small problems and I can not get any further, because I have insufficient knowledge of css and javascript coding:

1) All the figcaptions for all the slides are visible at the same time. Is it possible to make only the active figcaption visible?

2) The lazyloading of images is not very smooth. Can it have a slight fade-in and fade-out effect?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the line where it says: `fixedElements: 'figcaption',` - this is self-explanatory, the figcaption element is fixed in the bottom right corner.
2. You could hide all images in advance with CSS `img {display: none;}`, give the first image `style="display: block;"` attribute and add an event in Javascript `afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){var loadedSlide = $(this).find('img');loadedSlide.fadeIn();}`. [Reference](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex)

You can view the full code in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNGdvr)

Comment: Thanks! The fade-in works nice. I am trying to let the figcaptions stay in the bottom right corner and fade in and out (not slide) with the images. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can set the `scrollingSpeed` to zero like so: `scrollingSpeed: 0,` but I tried that and it will only work for the first round of slides, once you go over the slides again (2nd round) `fadeIn()` doesn't work anymore. For this to work you have to `fadeOut()` or use `css('display','none')` for previous image **AND** fadeIn() next image on change of slides. By the way, if that was the answer to your question accept it as an answer, don't leave the question open :)

Comment: There is a "V" under the arrows on the left